# Remove duplicate list of integers present inside a list of list without considering ordering of the lists of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, nested-lists

```
l1 = [[1, 2, -1], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, -1], [1, -1, 2]]
```

For my case
`[1, 2, -1]` is considered equal to `[2, 1, -1]` is the same as `[1, -1, 2]`. Essentially, ordering does not matter.

```
[1, 2, -1] = [2, 1, -1] = [1, -1, 2]
```

In cases like above, I need to keep only 1 of those 3 (any one of those three would do).

So after removing duplicates, the list must now have `l1 = [[1, 2, -1], [1, 0, 1]]` or `l1 = [[2, 1, -1], [1, 0, 1]]` or `l1 = [[1, -1, 2], [1, 0, 1]]`

I've tried sorting the individual lists (but this makes me lose the order in which the triplets were seen) and putting each individual list in a dictionary (`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`)

**Note:**

When I say "without considering ordering of the lists of integers", I mean that if there are 3 lists inside my list of lists with the same integers, ordered differently? Those 3 lists are considered the same! You are allowed to remove 2 out of those 3 lists, but preserve the ordering of the unremoved list,

I gave example which indicated that for my list of list `l1 = [[1, 2, -1], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, -1], [1, -1, 2]]`, `[[-1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1]]` is not acceptable, since `[-1, 1, 2]` is not actually present in the original array in that exact sequence! `[-1, 1, 2] = [1, 2, -1] = [2, 1, -1] = [1, -1, 2]` IS TRUE! IF I HAD THOSE 4 ELEMENTS IN MY LIST. But, I do not have [-1, 1, 2] in my list of lists!

**Also important:**

I may have duplicate elements inside the list of list of integers.

```
l1 = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [-1, 0, 1]]
```

Here: `[1, 0, 0]` = `[0, 1, 0]`, When returning my output, I will need one of those two to be removed.

The point I want to emphasize is that there are `2` zeros in those individual lists (I think this is important detail too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one solution using the 3rd party [`toolz`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library. Note [`compose`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.compose) and [`unique`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.unique) recipes are lazy and easy to extract from the respective source code if you do not have access to the library.

Notice we sort each sublist and then convert to an immutable `tuple`. This allows `unique` to form and track a `set` of values for O(1) lookup.

```
from toolz import unique, compose

l1 = [[1, 2, -1], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, -1], [1, -1, 2]]

res = list(unique(l1, key=compose(tuple, sorted)))

print(res)

[[1, 2, -1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Source code: [`toolz.compose`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/toolz/functoolz.html#compose), [`toolz.unique`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/toolz/itertoolz.html#unique)

Comment: Can this be done without using third-party libraries?

Comment: @Abhishek, Yes, copy the functions from the 2 links at the bottom of my answer :).

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the list using `sorted` and then check and append to result.

**Ex:**

```
l1 = [[1, 2, -1], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, -1], [1, -1, 2]]
checkVal = []
r = []
for i in l1:
    val = sorted(i)
    if val not in checkVal:
        checkVal.append(val)
        r.append(i)
print(r)
```

**output:**

```
[[1, 2, -1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Okay, so when I said `without considering ordering of the lists of integers`, I meant, that 3 lists, ordered differently are considered the same! but when returning one of the lists, the ordering of that list must be preserved.

I gave example which indicated that, `[[-1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1]]` is not acceptable, since `[-1, 1, 2]` is not actually present in the original array in that exact sequence! `[-1, 1, 2] = [1, 2, -1] = [2, 1, -1] = [1, -1, 2]` when it comes to choosing which 3 out of the 4 to remove. But, I do not have `[-1, 1, 2]` in my list of lists!

Comment: I suggest using a set of sorted tuples for `in` lookup

Comment: @Abhishek. Sorry I do not understand. Your output is the same as I have

Comment: @Rakesh: I ran your exact same code, I get `[[-1, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1]]` as my output!

Comment: With same data?

Comment: @Rakesh willing to send you a screenshot of Jupyter Notebook output. If you want to see, type your email id here (if sharing personal information is allowed and acceptable in comments). Only doing this so you see what I see and get thoroughly convinced.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve the same effect without using any 3rd-party library:

```
l1 = [[1, 2, -1], [1, 0, 1], [2, 1, -1], [1, -1, 2]]
seen = set()

out = []
for l in l1:
    t = tuple(sorted(l))
    if t in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(t)
    out.append(l)

print(out)
```